# Error while running debian on Arm6 based phone

Tags: linux

I have cynogenmod7 on my optimus one phone. I followed [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=996746) to run debian on it. When I give this command:

```
busybox mount -o loop,noatime $kit/debian.img $mnt
```

I get a `no loop device, file doesn’t exist error`. I tried setting up more loop devises like loop1, loop2 so on, even tried loop99 but still I got the same error. Is there any work-around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you follow the tutorial exactly unless you know what you're doing (well, unless you know what you're doing, you shouldn't be attempting to install foreign system, like Debian, over Android; the tutorial said it clearly: `If you are following this tutorial only because you want to /flex on your friends and you don't know anything about linux, then you really _should_ stop reading this tutorial.`).

Make sure that the shell variables `$kit` and `$mnt` are defined and have the appropriate values (if you follow the tutorial correctly, then `$kit` should have the value `/system/sd` and `$mnt` should have the value `/data/local/mnt`).